# High CPU usage with std::vector of strings + std::search and std::boyer_moore_horspool_searcher

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, c++17

I have a list of strings stored in a vector. These strings are std::wstring and have variable length, some are 20 characters and some are even 100.

The data being searched in is also std::wstring, but quite huge (some 500kb text, some even 10mb text).

Searching on the mighty Google and doing some tests, the fastest way to search for strings is [std::boyer_moore_horspool_searcher](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/boyer_moore_horspool_searcher), it cannot even be compared to [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Everything is "cool" and working accordingly, despite the CPU usage. I really need to have a lower CPU usage, because at the moment (and I`m still not done adding needle strings) my software is using up to 10% CPU + 50-120 Mbps I/O on my 12 core CPU.

To give you an example of what I`m doing, I've put together this small example (can't post large data):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::wstring Data = L"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. "
        L"Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"
        L" when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. "
        L"It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."
        L" It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,"
        L" and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
   
    std::vector<std::wstring> Strings;
    Strings.reserve(5);

    Strings.push_back(L"Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.");
    Strings.push_back(L"The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested.");
    Strings.push_back(L"Banana");
    Strings.push_back(L" It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,");
    Strings.push_back(L"It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.");

    for (auto const& String : Strings)
    {
        auto it = std::search(Data.begin(), Data.end(), std::boyer_moore_horspool_searcher(String.begin(), String.end()));

        if (it != Data.end())
            std::wcout << L"The string " << String << L" found at offset "
            << it - Data.begin() << '\n';
        else
            std::wcout << L"The string " << String << L" not found\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with VS 2019 and ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17), Release and maximum optimizations.

Please give me some advice on how to reduce this CPU and I/O load. I`m even considering having compiled time needle strings if that helps, or even [strstr](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/).

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: And what is the **real** issue you are trying to solve? Do you want your search to be slower?

Comment: @IInspectable Well of course not... but I would like to reduce CPU usage if possible. I know what I`m asking is a bit unrealistic but hopefully there is a way.

Comment: You should give `find` a chance, but not `std::find`, but `std::wstring::find` member function, it has been heavily optimized over time and works often faster then expected, while `std::boyer_moore_horspool_searcher` needs to set some internal data structures before it even begins searching. 
Other then that you could reduce the maximum CPU usage by giving your app a low priority on the OS level, but there's usually no real reason to do so.

Comment: @Kaldrr Already tried it... it's very slow and uses a lot of CPU. wcsstr seems to be super fast, lower CPU usage, but it does not work properly in my context. I`m still trying to figure it out.

Comment: **Why** do you need lower CPU resource consumption? Your CPU is there for the sole reason of being used. It's an odd requirement to not want to use something for what its intended purpose is. You can be confident that your C++ Standard Library is of very high quality and that your OS is well prepared to arbitrate resource contention.

Comment: @IInspectable I understand, but try to explain that to PC end users...

Comment: If you find a need to explain that, have a technical writer add a section to your application's manual. That's not a programming problem.

Comment: @IInspectable We both know this is an endless discussion and battle with end users...

Comment: I don't know why you experience feedback as *"an endless discussion and battle"* rather than "a dialog and opportunity to improve", but maybe that's the problem that needs fixing. Again, from personal experience, users don't fire up Task Manager unless you give them a reason to. That reason is, in the overwhelming majority of cases, a UI that's unresponsive. Give them a UI that responds to **every** user input in less than a few 10s of milliseconds, and they won't open Task Manager and (falsely) attribute high CPU load to a sluggish UI experience. I do, and I have happy (and demanding) users.